# Как раскрасить такую таблицу?

Tags: html, css

Нельзя использовать `:nth-chil(i)`, `:nth-child(an+b)` и `:not`. Только `odd`, `first`, `last` и `even`.

[image: Шахматная доска]

Comment: К чему такие ограничения? Если это учебное задание, то приложите вашу попытку.

Comment: Да, в том-то и дело, что это задание.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nvanyukova/pen/jOqGNYd

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var row = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  row += "<td/>";
row = "<tr>" + row + "</tr>";

var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  html += row;

document.getElementById("board").innerHTML = html;
```

```css
#board {
  background: gray;
}

#board td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#board tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
#board tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}

#board tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
#board tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}

#board tr:first-child td:nth-child(even),
#board tr:first-child td:nth-child(odd),
#board tr:last-child td:nth-child(even),
#board tr:last-child td:nth-child(odd),
#board tr:nth-child(odd) td:first-child,
#board tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child,
#board tr:nth-child(odd) td:last-child,
#board tr:nth-child(even) td:last-child
{
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="board"></table>
```

Comment: Да, это почти помогает) Но проблема в том, что important использовать нельзя.

Comment: @NadyaWilde Кхм, кхм, ну давайте уберем `important`.